# Vega: Displaying multiple dataset values in tooltip

Tags: vega

See Vega gist here: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/35dac51206b658f67b7e3b2eba284e20/vega_bindfit.json

I'm trying to write a Vega visualisation that displays 3 datasets and shows a tooltip containing their individual datapoint values on mouseover. I've managed to do this via a Voronoi transform for a single dataset in the visualisation above. Ideally I would like to show values in the tooltip for all 3 datasets that are displayed in the visualisation.

I have considered using a lookup transform to combine all of the required datasets together and pulling the tooltip values from that, however that seems quite messy.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Relevant code:

```
  "marks": {
    ...
    {
      "name": "vPoints",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {
        "data": "outputFit"
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "xValue": {
            "field": "guestOverHost",
            "scale": "mainX"
          },
          "yValue": {
            "value": 0
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "transparent"
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 10
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "transparent"
          },
          "strokeWidth": {
            "value": 0.5
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vCell",
      "type": "path",
      "from": {
        "data": "vPoints"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {
            "value": "transparent"
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "transparent"
          },
          "isVoronoi": {
            "value": true
          },
          "strokeWidth": {
            "value": 0.35
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum.datum"
          }
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "voronoi",
          "x": "datum.xValue",
          "y": "datum.yValue",
          "size": [
            {
              "signal": "width"
            },
            {
              "signal": "height"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```